# Exception while connecting weblogic server using EJB - Invalid Subject: principals=[weblogic, Administrators]

Tags: ejb, weblogic, subject

I have a thread running in my local weblogic server that runs once in a day which tries to establish connection with another application running in a different weblogic server. Whenever my method creates a remote object and tries to call remote method i get below exception

> **[Security:090398]Invalid Subject: principals=[weblogic, Administrators]**

Here is my code:

```
    Properties myEnv = new Properties();
    myEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    myEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3//123.345.234.123:1234");
    myEnv.put( Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username );
    myEnv.put( Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password );        
    InitialContext context;
    Object lookupObj;
    try {
        context = new InitialContext(_contextEnv);  
        lookupObj = context.lookup("ejb.lookup.bean");
        MyHome home = (MyHome) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(lookupObj, MyHome.class);
        MyRemote remote =home.create();
        if (null != context) {
            try {
                context.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            //

            }
        }
        return remote;
    }  catch (Exception e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Can anyone tell what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think both weblogic server instances are running in 2 distinct domains.
So, you need to enable a trust between the 2 domains.
Have a look at this doc : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13707/domain.htm#SECMG402

Also, don't forget to close the JNDI context in a finally clause when it is more more needed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case，I just add parameters

```
-Dweblogic.security.crypto.verifyPriorDigest=true 
-Dweblogic.security.crypto.generatePriorDigest=true
```

to my JAVA_OPTIONS with Weblogic Server 12.2.1.4.0,for example,if you use nodeMangerService,you can edit your startNodeManager.sh and add the parameters.